Serializing and Deserializing OAuth2AuthorizationRequest using jackson grives MismatchedInputException
I am trying to serialize and deserialize an object of class OAuth2AuthorizationRequest.
I get the following error on deserialization:
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: 
Cannot construct instance of `org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.endpoint.OAuth2AuthorizationResponseType` (although at least one Creator exists): 
cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator) 
at [Source: REDACTED (`StreamReadFeature.INCLUDE_SOURCE_IN_LOCATION` disabled); line: 1, column: 80] (through reference chain: org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.endpoint.OAuth2AuthorizationRequest["responseType"])

public final class OAuth2AuthorizationRequest implements Serializable {
    // ...
    
    public OAuth2AuthorizationResponseType getResponseType();
    
    // ...
}

The class OAuth2AuthorizationResponseType has no default constructor and is causing the error.
I understand that this is because there is no default constructor, but as it is an external class, I cannot modify it.
I checked multiple resources online, but most involve adding a public constructor or a constructor with @JsonCreator annotation.
Is there a workaround for this error?

Note: I couldn't find a solution using Jackson ObjectMapper but as I am not concerned with the format in which the object gets serialized, I used a serializer called Kryo and it works for me.


I have a feeling that you doing something invalid, however you can always create a decorator and delegate the operation to original object

Thanks. The problem in the link is very similar. But as I cannot edit the external class OAuth2AuthorizationResponseType, the solutions provided in the link mostly involve adding a default constructor or using the @JsonCreator annotation don't work for me.

I tried every in jackson, but it just does not work. Finally I went along with Kryo. refer (https://www.baeldung.com/kryo#3-java-serializer) and it works. (If Json formats are what you want, go with jackson)
